# Слово МНОГО. Синтаксическая функция

Tags: синтаксис

***В этой кладовой несколько перегородок. - В этой кладовой много перегородок.***

**Какова синтаксическая роль слов "несколько" и "много" в данных предложениях?**

Я думаю, что словосочетания "несколько перегородок" и "много перегородок" - это подлежащие при подразумеваемом сказуемом "есть". Но существует мнение, что "много" - сказуемое.Я бы согласилась с ним, если бы"много" стояло после слова "перегородок", ср.: ***В этой кладовой перегородок много.*** Здесь "много" действительно сказуемое. Слово категории состояния.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*В этой кладовой несколько перегородок. - В этой кладовой много перегородок.*

"Несколько перегородок" и "много перегородок" - слитные сочетания, являющиеся подлежащими  в эллиптических предложениях. Пропущено сказуемое, которое можно легко подставить: есть, существует, имеется. Пропущенное *ЕСТЬ* здесь не глагол-связка, а знаменательный  глагол со значением бытия. Связкой он является в составных именных сказуемых, а здесь простое глагольное, но занимает нулевую позицию.

Согласна, что сказуемым сочетание будет в Вашем примере: *В этой кладовой перегородок много.*

Только не категория состояния, а всё то же наречие, часть речи не меняется.Это **безлично-генитивные** предложения. Иногда указывают только на слово ***много*** как сказуемое, иногда вместе с родительным падежом существительного, а кто-то из учёных просто говорит: **грамматическая основа**, не называя, что это - подлежащее или сказуемое. Сейчас ведь в отдельных учебниках и в школе говорят просто о грамматической основе в односоставном предложении и даже подчёркивают её **тремя чертами**, чтобы не акцентировать внимание на терминах.

Comment: Да, Людмила, насчёт ЕСТЬ я написала не подумав, по инерции, так сказать). Совершенно с Вами согласна.

Answer (score 1):

1) В кладовой (есть/было) **много перегородок.** В кладовой (есть/было) **пять перегородок**. В кладовой **нет/не было  перегородок**. В кладовой (есть/было ) **достаточно перегородок.**

Всё это **количественно-бытийные предложения** (отрицательные или оценочные), и вопрос об их классификации является дискуссионным.

2) Но в любом случае эти предложения **следует отличать от односоставных номинативных предложений**, которые выражают существование предмета или нахождение предмета в зоне наблюдателя. Номинативные предложения не имеют прошедшего времени и парадигмы, например: Он вошел в комнату, осмотрелся. Картины на стене, несколько старинных стульев, статуэтки на столе. (Нельзя сказать: были картины).

3) А вот **количественно-бытийные предложения  имеют прошедшее время и парадигму.** Поэтому их относят к **двусоставным предложениям:** (1) эллиптического типа (обстоятельство ― количественное сочетание в роли подлежащего) в настоящем времени или (2) количественное сочетание в роли подлежащего – сказуемое ***было*** в прошедшем времени.

4) **Если сделать перестановку,** то смысл и грамматика **НЕ МЕНЯЮТСЯ**: **Перегородок в кладовой много. Перегородок в кладовой было много.** Такая перестановка/инверсия рассматривается как **актуализация (выделение) формы Р.п, на нее в этом случае падает логическое ударение.**

Такое решение (в части актуализации Р.п.)  дает Грамматика-80.